# Increase camera fps?

Tags: opencv, camera

I need an eye tracker for an experiment, which is not required but would greatly reduce my workload. So I wanted to build a DIY eye-tracker. I'm having a problem with the Frame Rate, a decent eye-tracker would be working @500Hz, or at least 200Hz.

The highest fps camera I can get on market is 200fps, but I want push it to 500.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum fps of cameras is to do with the internals of the camera, so there is no way to override it using software.  The quoted maximum fps is usually for the maximum resolution available on that camera though, higher frame rates are normally achievable if you are willing to lower the resolution.

Comment: and are willing to lower the life expectancy of the hardware. One reason for restricting the speed is to allow the sensor to bleed some heat, preventing it from overheating and killing itself.

Comment: Nice, Thanks! I'll buy several of them, and primarily look for programmable modules.